# Does "Streamline the tone" make sense?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

When using the same tense/style for all bullet points in a resume, can we say the following?

> Let's streamline the tone for all bullet points.

Comment: We'd say something like "Let's keep a consistent (or uniform)  tone/style/grammatical structure for all the bullet points." *Streamline* has a different meaning, e.g. reduce the length/complexity of the points--simplify their structure. On the other hand, we could *change the tone* of the bullet points if it too familiar/informal or has too much technical language.

Comment: Streamline is OK, but it doesn't go with "tone". You could streamline the *format*, such as by making them all terse in the same manner, rather than having some as full sentences and others as just fragments.

Comment: What do you think 'streamlining a tone' could possibly mean?

Answer (score 1):

No - putting bullet points into a common tense/style is likely neither streamlining them, nor affecting their tone.

"Streamline" means to simplify and remove unnecessary material. You could streamline bullet points by making them more concise even eliminating some, but changing the tense or style of a bullet point likely would not streamline it in any way. I suppose you could consider consistent style to be streamlining if it greatly enhances the "flow" by avoiding distracting tense shifts.

"Tone" refers to the general attitude of a piece of writing. The tense doesn't really contribute to the tone of piece, nor does the grammatical style very much - putting all the bullets in the same tense with grammatical parallel structure is likely not revising the tone at all. I struggle to envision how one could "streamline a tone", as a tone is an overall impression that doesn't have extraneous detail in the first place.

You could instead say:

"Let's put the bullets in parallel structure."

"Let's use consistent style for the bullets points."

Comment: The primary meaning of "[streamline](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/streamline)" isn't to simplify - it's to reduce air resistance. A square is simple but it's not streamlined.

Comment: @StuartF We are clearly not talking about streamlining in the context of aerodynamics, and most people would only rarely use that context at all. Did you notice that the top synonym listed on the page you linked is, in fact, *simplify*?